# NHibernate - Money Type - Multiple Fields in Table

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I am attempting to save financial transactions to a database using NHibernate and have come across a number of blog posts suggesting the use of a *Money Type* whereby the amount is stored as a double and the currency is stored as a string - i.e. there will be two fields in the database.

For my purposes, I will have multiple financial records in the same table - e.g. Unit Price, Tax in dollars, savings in dollars, etc. The above approach will work, but will result in duplicated data as there will be a column for the currency type of each of these (in this example 3) fields. This is unnecessary as the currency will always be the same for savings as it is for price, etc. - if it is dollars for one, it will be dollars for the other...

Has anyone run into a similar issue and, if so, can you tell me the solution you ended up with?

Thanks

JP

Comment: My initial reaction is: just live with the duplication; it will drastically simplify your object model.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same thing many places too, so far I have seen no explanation of why.  What good is it?  This is not how people do business or how a logical system works.   If I am doing international business from the US, my systems will still have an internal basis of the dollar.

Currency is important as a boundary condition for an event, where you need an exchange rate.  Even an international bank. I currently send all my drug money, USD, to the Caymans where my money is available to me also accounted in dollars.  Maybe yours is in euros.  So they get it, and what they do is convert both to whatever currency they use internally, sea shells whatever.  Now they have to keep up with this stuff, but what they have to know at any given time is the exchange rate between dollars/sea shells to know how much they are in to me for, and sea shells/euros to know how much they are in to you for. This little goody does not do squat for them either it is a value object, how could it?  Currency in this case would be fixed at the account level, not a bunch of these things floating around.

In general currency will be fixed by something else, like you observe, at a row level.   A row of data is related, you should be able to do math on money values, in which case the currency in a row would have to be the same.  Maybe I do business in Europe and have to quote in euros.  I might want to record for historical purposes a quote versus payment in both currencies.  I question if this is a single row design but if I decided it were, a Money object you describe is a single value object with two components.  It should be considered a single entity, and I think what I am describing here is semantically different from a "Money" object and might as well be described explicitly by decimal/currency columns that we do not try to composite as a sing;e Money value because they cannot be compared or have math done on them.

I would just not go this route because leads to confusing subtle inconsistencies in semantics, and probably adds nothing.  Where are you ever really going to use it that a row-wise currency would not give you the same thing, typically in a more rational fashion?

But if a manager insists you do something that is fundamentally pointless or worse, in terms of NHibernate you have declared a single atomic entity, Money that happens to have 2 components, a decimal and string.  Because Money is now a single atomic unit, you have to always have both columns for each money, there is no workaround for avoiding the duplicate columns.